# How to fetch bodies of multiple revisions of same document Apache CouchDB?

Tags: apache, couchdb, couchapp

A similar question was asked here [Getting full list of revisions on document level using CouchDB-Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966427/getting-full-list-of-revisions-on-document-level-using-couchdb-python), but what I want to do is also to **retrieve the bodies of each revision of the same document in one request**. I want to effectively build a revision list also showing the past document bodies.

According to the HTTP API: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API,

"You can **fetch the bodies of multiple revisions** at once using the parameter **open_revs=["rev1","rev2",...]**, or you can fetch all leaf revisions using open_revs=all (see Replication_and_conflicts). The JSON returns an array of objects with an "ok" key pointing to the document, or a "missing" key pointing to the rev string"

However, when I run my query with the **AJAX** option 
**open_revs: ["3-9e93308666d43721e80580acaedd149b","2-6a3187f50d51756820f1908eab7fcf3f","1-e9a0482bf9a120bd03fb5ff03cdd2d3d"]** , I get an invalid_json request returned from the Erlang server.

I have checked my revision numbers which I retrieved from an array **revs_info** parameter, and still no success.

I was thinking that another possible method is to iterate over the **rev_info** array and requery the server for each revision body, but this seems too inefficient.

What is the correct method to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the argument `include_docs=true`? Haven't seen the request you made so I can't tell if it's relevant but if it's a request for a view, [here's where it's documented](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API).

Comment: The request I am trying to execute is:
GET /database/b30f72bf8a745d19094d2e79b104be16?open_revs=3-9e93308666d43721e80580acaedd149b%2C2-6a3187f50d51756820f1908eab7fcf3f%2C1-e9a0482bf9a120bd03fb5ff03cdd2d3d
 I passed in an array 3 revision ids of the document I want to retrieve, which should return 3 separate revision bodies of the same doc. Reference here for open_rev http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API
I am using openDoc function call from jquery.couch.js and passing open_revs: ["3-9e93349b","2-6a38eab7fcf3f","1-5ff03cdd2d3d"] as one of the options. Revision numbers are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `?open_revs` parameter is a JSON-encoded array of strings. In the example you gave in the comment to the other answer, you're not including either the brackets or the quotes, just the comma-separated IDs. That's why you're getting a JSON error.

(Yes, both the brackets and the quotes have to be URL-escaped too!)